# bash script stops logging in the middle

Tags: bash

I trimmed my script down but my log function stops working and I don't understand why.  I copied a script that returns values through stdout so we can't put 'anything' in stdout or it corrupts the set of bash scripts.  I am on macOS Catalina

```
    #!/bin/bash

    set -e

    function log {
       MESSAGE=$1
       >&2 echo "$MESSAGE"
    }

    log "message works"

    command -v tac >&2
    log "test and not work too"
    TAC_EXISTS=$?
    command -v tail >&2
    TAIL_EXISTS=$?

    log "message not work"
```

Comment: did you run each line of this code manually from the cmd line (excepting your definition for `log()`)? Also, having `set -e` means your script will quit anytime it has an error. Find the line that doesn't execute and it is the line before that is causing a problem. Good luck.

Comment: Presumably one of the commands (`tac` or `tail`) doesn't exist, so the `command -v <something` exits with an error, so `set -e` makes the shell exit at that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
function log {
       MESSAGE=$1
       >&2 echo "$MESSAGE"
    }
```

Why don't you write it as

```
function log {
       >&2 echo "$1" > &2
}
```

Comment: No idea, I took the scripts from a git repo https://github.com/zladovan as it was the closest working mono-repo I saw with gradle and then hacked up the scripts to not depend on CI to do the monorepo and only depend on git instead.